# Alternative for manager class with template child class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I have an `Expression` class that is the base class for other types:

```
template <typename T>
class Expression : public ExpressionProxy {
    public:
        ExpressionType type;
        T value;

        Expression(ExpressionType type, T value) {
            this->type = type;
            this->value = value;
        }

        virtual T GetValue() {
            return this->value;
        }

        virtual ExpressionType GetType() {
            return this->type;
        }
};
```

for example, `IntegerExpression`:

```
class IntegerExpression: public Expression<int> {
    public:
        IntegerExpression(int value) : Expression<int>(ExpressionType::Integer, value) {
            
        }
};
```

I do this to both get interchangeable values (like `IntegerExpression` returning an int, `FractionExpression` returning a float, etc...), handle other more complicated expressions like `SumExpression`, and know the type of `Expression` with `ExpressionType` instead of downcasting or using `typeid`.

But, when templates are used, I can't use my `Manager` class, which only consist of a `std::vector` and an adding/indexing function (the below code won't work, it's just for demonstration purpose of the Manager class):

```
std::vector<Expression> controlledComponents;
ExpressionManager() {
    this->controlledComponents.reserve(100000);
}

Expression* AddNewControlledComponent(Expressionargs) {
    if ((int) this->controlledComponents.size() >= this->maxElement) {
        std::cerr << "Manager: Overflow. Please resize array." << '\n';
        return nullptr;
    }

    this->controlledComponents.push_back(args);
    return &this->controlledComponents[this->controlledComponents.size()-1];
}

Expression* GetControlledComponent(int idx) {
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= (int) this->controlledComponents.size()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return &this->controlledComponents[idx];
}

const static int maxElement = 100000;
```

(I know I should probably use dynamic object pooling and smart pointers, but please bear with me here.)

As the `Expression` class will require a "typename" to be declared.

I could either create `Manager<T>` class for all of my type (which is unfavorable as I have a lot of them) or use an empty proxy class that `Expression` inherit from:

```
class ExpressionProxy {

};
```

which defeats the purpose of the template class in the first place.

So I want to know if there are any solutions or possible alternatives to this issue, as I am not very familiar with C++ templates.

Tl;dr: If I don't use templates for `Expression`, I would have to downcast for custom-type values on derived classes (the alternative is using `std::string` or `std::vector`, which isn't great either). If I do use templates, I'm not able to store and use `Expression` effectively.

Comment: What do you hope for a client of the manager to be able to do without knowing `T`?

Comment: `std::vector<Expression>` is invalid anyway. You either need a separate vector for each `T`, or use dynamic polymorphism and use some code to dispatch to static polymorphism.

Comment: @DavisHerring the manager doesn't do anything outside of creating and maintaining the expressions. So I'm wondering if I could create a universal manager for all generic type T instead of creating a custom manager for each one.

Comment: Suppose you somehow managed to implement it. The caller writes `Expression* expr = manager.GetControlledComponent(0);` and it somehow works. What next? How do you envision the caller would use `expr`?

Comment: @WeijunZhou my bad, that code isn't going to run, I just add it in to demonstrate what my `Manager` class looks like. I edited the post.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik For instance, if I called getValue() on that, I was expecting it to return the value according to the typename.

Now that I think about it, that does seems a bit problematic; maybe I should just go with creating all the Manager type.

Comment: @silverfox It sounds like your idea revolves around `std::any` and coroutines without finding purchase

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie can you elaborate more on how I can use `std::any` here?

Comment: "Hey, give me the expression number 3276" doesn't look like a very useful request. In what kind of application would you need it?

Comment: `std::any` is just a fashionable way to use `dynamic_cast` without spelling the keyword explicitly.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI "what kind of application would you need it?" mm, it could be 
 something modBUS\CAN\SCADA visualization\control related, but  it's a weird implementation, usually object model mapping happens first, or something like a spreadsheet app?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It's for a CAS module. I want each expression to have a type so I don't have to downcast it, but also generic 'cause each `Expression` may have multiple operands that are also `Expression`. Currently I just don't know which better way to implement this.

Comment: How would users of your CAS add their own types? By writing a piece of C++ code? Or is it restricted to a fixed set of types and the users cannot extend it?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yes, currently it's fixed. So I just define everything on my end.

Comment: Well if it's fixed, then each expression has a fixed number of operands of known types. Storing them in a homogenous array defeats the purpose of strong typing. (You don't replace every `struct` with a homogenous array of fields). You can store the operands in a tuple that preserves typing, and still allows access by a (constant) element index. For purposes of traversing an expression tree, you can generically enumerate the tuple elements upcasting each to `ExpressionProxy`, so that you can pass them to the visitor.

Comment: OTOH if you make your type system extensible, your CAS types are no longer C++ types, but C++ values. The templatization disappears, and the problem with it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I kinda don't get what you're saying. For each `Expression` I will obviously know the number of operands, or "subexpression", like `Sum` will have two subexpressions. The thing I won't know is which type they are. There could be a `Sum` of two `Symbol`s, two `Fraction`s, two `Expression`s,... So in a way I kind of need both homogenous and non-homogenous-ness if that make sense? Or I could just store all values as `string` and deal with the conversion I guess.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you want a computer algebra system in which the evaulation of expressions may result in different types *of values*. The expressions themselves could just be a tree of objects inheriting from an expression base class but then you want integer expressions to evaluate to integers and other expressions evaluate to floats. So make *the value* type model this i.e. use an std::variant as the type that MyExpression::evaluate returns.

Comment: "So in a way I kind of need both homogenous and non-homogenous-ness if that make sense?" You can put it this way, yes.

Comment: @jwezorek Everything can be an `std::variant` (or an `std::string`), but not everything needs to be.

Comment: @jwezorek That's a good idea! So to get my value back to its type I only have to use `get()` on the `std::variant value` instead of having to downcast a whole class, which seems to be safer and quicker. I'll try that out.